# How can I implement a schmitt trigger into a differentiating op-amp in order to reduce the signal noise of the output?

Tags: schmitt-trigger

The circuit is driven by an LDR, but the output signal is too noisy. Is there a way hysteresis can clean up the noise in such circuit?

Comment: Circuit diagram would help. Are you looking for an on/off output?

Comment: Google is your friend.  Putting the following string into Google brings up more than 100,000 hits: "non-inverting schmitt trigger"

Comment: I have a programmed micro-controller that will read the change in Vout when there's a dip in the LDR. So, I need a cleaner output signal for the micro-controller. Not necessarily an on/off

Comment: Then you are looking for a low pass filter not a schmitt trigger

Comment: How does the word "differentiating" have an impact on this question? Why do you mention "op-amp" when your comments refer to using an MCU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to give a differential amplifier hysteresis by adding positive feed-back, and this will create a Schmitt trigger. However: A Schmitt trigger produces a digital on/off signal as its output from an input analogue input - the trigger has hysteresis - that is the output turns on when the input level is at a higher than the trigger level for it to turn off again. As such it is not suitable for your application.

What you are looking for is a low-pass filter. Probably a simple first order filter consisting of a single resistor and capacitor on the output of the amplifier will suffice.